# Creating an IM Client in Java

Tags: java

I'm creating a simple IM Client where a client instance can connect to the server on a port then send to and receive messages from other connected users.

Since I'm getting the input from the client's `System.in`, I can't differentiate when the client is trying to register a username or send a message. How can I effectively differentiate what is what on the server side, when text is received from a client?

I have considered requiring the client to specify the user to send to, which would act as an indicator that it was a message. This would be similar to in-game chats where you type "/tell username message".

Comment: Could you clarify this question?

Comment: It sounds like you want to write your own protocol, to some extent. Using an existing protocol would be a lot less work and much more secure. Consider looking into some of the ones mentioned in the answers below before trying to write your own.

Answer (score 4):

You should consider implementing or using a library for an already existing protocol, such as [IRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat) or [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP).

If you'd rather not do that, try to take inspiration from them. For example, the IRC protocol is all about [commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_Relay_Chat_commands). To write a private message to a user or to send a message to a channel, you send a [`PRIVMSG`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_Relay_Chat_commands#PRIVMSG) command to the server, then the sever parses the command, extracts the command name, recipient and message, and then takes care to send the message to the recipient.

Comment: To further support Radu's answer: the IRC and XMPP authors have already thought about, discussed, and settled on an optimal solution to the exact question you've asked.  Save yourself some time and don't reinvent the wheel.